# Sending file from SP2010 to WSS using Work Flow

Tags: development, web-services, wss-3.0

I would like to send a file from one document library in SP 2010 to another document library in WSS 3.0. I was thinking web services would be the best way to do this. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Can web services be used to post documents outside of the SharePoint environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the workflow send an email to the WSS library, instead of using webservices.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to Use Web services that will download file from SP 2010 and then Upload it to WSS 3.0

[Download A folder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103503/How-to-upload-download-a-document-in-SharePoint-20)

Uploading a document to WSS 3.0 can be done using this code

[Uploading Document](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/10/19/add-new-document-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-using-c/)

But it entirely depends on your scenario as how you will download/upload them to relative servers.

Comment: I was under the assumption SharePoint.dlls can only be used on the same server as the request, thats why I need to use WebServices. Your links are not for web services...

Comment: with respect I wonder if anyone gonna develop webservices and give you the code you need, and even in Web Services you need same code to make it work, It would be great if you read a little bit about webservices before asking anything else please :)

Comment: It's ok, I used a mailservice to send the file across to the other environment.

Comment: @TimeToThine: I think OP is just saying they solved the problem another way - not that your answer was wrong.

Comment: @SPDoctor thanks for looking at it, question title and explanation was misleading then what mike wanted to do, so I edited it now :)

Comment: I appreciate your response TimeToThine. See my updated answer.

Comment: I am a developer, I think about everything programmatically :D lol